# How to dynamically add reference to parent in a javascript multilevel object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

In the tree object I'm working with, a node may have a 'children' property that can contain an array of child nodes. It's a concept for a multilevel menu structure.

What I'd like to achieve is to dynamically add a reference to the parent in the children.

I'm stuck at the point where I should mutate the original object. I cannot figure out how to do that properly.

The code snippet begins with an example object. It is followed by a recursive function that visits every node and holds reference to the parent, but does not modify the object. Then there is a function that modifies the object, but to only 3 levels in depth.

```js
var obj = {
  id: "a",
  children: [{
      id: "b",
      children: [{
        id: "c"
      }]
    },
    {
      id: "d"
    }
  ]
};


function visitNode(node, parent) {
  if (node.children) {
    console.log('node with children', node, 'parent\'s ID is:', parent.id);
    node.children.forEach(child => visitNode(child, node));
  } else {
    console.log('node with no children:', node, 'parent\'s ID is:', parent.id);
  }
}
visitNode(obj, {id: null});

function mutate(obj) {
  obj.parentId = null;
  if (obj.children) {
    obj.children.forEach((child, i) => {
      obj.children[i].parentId = obj.id;
      if (child.children) {
        child.children.forEach((child2, j) => {
          obj.children[i].children[j].parentId = obj.children[i].id;
        })
      }
    })
  }
}

mutate(obj);
console.log('mutated object', obj);
```

Comment: do you like to add a back reference to the parent?

Comment: @NinaScholz: yes, that's what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive function which is called with the actual object and the parent reference. If children exist, the children are iterated and the function is called again with the actual reference.

This proposal creates circular references to the object (that means, [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) may not work).

```js
function setParent(object, parent) {
    object.parent = parent;
    object.children && object.children.forEach(function (o) {
        setParent(o, object);
    });
}

var object = { id: "a", children: [{ id: "b", children: [{ id: "c" }] }, { id: "d" }] };

setParent(object);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```